# log4j2 configuration for graylog

Tags: java, log4j2, graylog3

We want to centralize all our java application logs on Graylog server. We use apache tomcat as a container and log4j for the logging framework.
**log4j2.xml**

```
        <Socket name="GELF" protocol="tcp" host="graylog.domain.com" port="12201">
            <GelfLayout host="%host">
                    <KeyValuePair key="projectName" value="magus"/>
                    <KeyValuePair key="level" value="%level"/>
                    <KeyValuePair key="timestamp" value="%d"/>
                    <KeyValuePair key="server" value="%host"/>
                    <KeyValuePair key="logStream" value="magus"/>
                    <KeyValuePair key="version" value="1.1"/>
                    <KeyValuePair key="projectName" value="magus"/>
                    <KeyValuePair key="logStream" value="magus"/>
                    <KeyValuePair key="className" value="%C"/>
                    <KeyValuePair key="simpleClassName" value="%C{1}"/>
            </GelfLayout>
    </Socket>
```

**Loggers**

```
    <Loggers>
       <Root level="INFO">
          <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
          <AppenderRef ref="LOG"/>
          <AppenderRef ref='GELF'/>
       </Root>
    </Loggers>
```

**log detail**

```
2021-01-26 20:05:01,343 http-nio-31381-exec-1 DEBUG Reconnecting /graylog.domain.com:12201
2021-01-26 20:05:01,344 http-nio-31381-exec-1 DEBUG Creating socket /graylog.domain.com:12201
2021-01-26 20:05:01,344 http-nio-31381-exec-1 DEBUG Closing SocketOutputStream    java.net.SocketOutputStream@8cb01fa
2021-01-26 20:05:01,345 http-nio-31381-exec-1 DEBUG Connection to graylog.domain.com:12201 reestablished: Socket[addr=/graylog.domain.com,port=12201,localport=41482]
```

As you see my application create a socket connection wiith gray log server. But we did not see any log on the Gray log server

**versions**
tomcat - 9.0.16.0
jdk - 1.8.0_201-b09(64 bit)
log4j2 - 1.12 / 1.14(both checked)
os - Linux 3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64
gray log - Graylog 3.0.2+1686930 on graylogsrv (Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_232 on Linux 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64)

**documentation**
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#GELFLayout

I want to use log4j2 other than extrnal library like `logstash-gelf`

**UPDATE**
this is the gray log server log

```
2021-01-27T12:18:45.079+04:00 ERROR [DecodingProcessor] Unable to decode raw message RawMessage{id=45f04b90-6078-11eb-80bf-00505696a882, journalOffset=2771397770, codec=gelf, payloadSize=11, timestamp=2021-01-27T08:18:45.065Z, remoteAddress=/graylog.domain:58258} on input <600ecd97f7c4b60478f4504e>.
2021-01-27T12:18:45.079+04:00 ERROR [DecodingProcessor] Error processing message RawMessage{id=45f04b90-6078-11eb-80bf-00505696a882, journalOffset=2771397770, codec=gelf, payloadSize=11, timestamp=2021-01-27T08:18:45.065Z, remoteAddress=/graylog.domain:58258}
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('�' (code 65533 / 0xfffd)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: �Y�n�8��h; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:456) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1906) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:749) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3850) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3799) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2397) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at org.graylog2.inputs.codecs.GelfCodec.decode(GelfCodec.java:127) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at org.graylog2.shared.buffers.processors.DecodingProcessor.processMessage(DecodingProcessor.java:150) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at org.graylog2.shared.buffers.processors.DecodingProcessor.onEvent(DecodingProcessor.java:91) [graylog.jar:?]
    at org.graylog2.shared.buffers.processors.ProcessBufferProcessor.onEvent(ProcessBufferProcessor.java:74) [graylog.jar:?]
    at org.graylog2.shared.buffers.processors.ProcessBufferProcessor.onEvent(ProcessBufferProcessor.java:42) [graylog.jar:?]
    at com.lmax.disruptor.WorkProcessor.run(WorkProcessor.java:143) [graylog.jar:?]
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedThreadFactory$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedThreadFactory.java:66) [graylog.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_232]
```

how can we get original data to find the error?

Comment: Why you have 2 key="logStream" parameters in question?

Comment: @AlekseiKurepin just duplicate. ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved. According to [documentation](https://docs.graylog.org/en/4.0/pages/gelf.html)

> GELF TCP does not support compression due to the use of the null byte (\0) as frame delimiter.

So after disabling compress on the `log4j2` configuration we saw our log on the gray log server. The below code snippet is a working example

```
<Socket name="GELF" protocol="tcp" host="graylog.domain.com" port="12201">
            <!-- gelf tcp does not support compression-->
            <GelfLayout includeStackTrace="true" host="${hostName}" includeThreadContext="true" includeNullDelimiter="true"
                  compressionType="OFF">
                
                <KeyValuePair key="host" value="${hostName}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="version" value="1.1"/>
                <!--<KeyValuePair key="short_message" value="$${event:Message}"/>--><!--   not required             -->
                <KeyValuePair key="application_name" value="${web:contextPathName}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="thread_id" value="$${event:ThreadId}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="thread_name" value="$${event:ThreadName}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="timestamp" value="$${event:Timestamp}"/>
                <!--<KeyValuePair key="level" value="1"/>--><!-- default level type is number so we don't use-->
                <KeyValuePair key="log_level" value="$${event:Level}"/><!-- for readabilty and filtering-->
            </GelfLayout>
        </Socket>
```